# Entity Framework Core "The entity type 'XXX' requires a primary key to be defined."

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

So I'm currently trying to create a code first migration with Entity Framework Core for a table that displays which lectures the application user has completed. My model looks like this:

```
public class LectureCompletion
{
    [Key,  Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Lecture")]
    public Lecture LectureId { get; set; }

    [Key,  Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public ApplicationUser UserId{ get; set; }

    public bool Completed { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use the `UserId` and the `LectureId` as the unique composite key. However I get this error:

> The entity type 'LectureCompletion' requires a primary key to be defined.

I don't understand why this is happening as I clearly have my key attributes in the correct positions? Am I able to use `ApplicationUser` as foreign/primary key?

Here is my `Lecture` model:

```
public class Lecture
{
    [Key]
    public int LectureId { get; set; }

    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public string LectureName { get; set; }
}
```

And my `ApplicationDBContext.cs`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Lecture> Lectures { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LectureCompletion> LectureCompletion { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't define a composite key with data annotation alone. You need to use Fluent API instead.

```
public class LectureCompletion
{
    // which is your case.
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Lecture))] 
    public int LectureId { get;set; }
    public Lecture Lecture { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ApplicationUser))]
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(builder);

     // Define composite key.
     builder.Entity<LectureCompletion>()
         .HasKey(lc => new { lc.LectureId, lc.UserId });
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! That worked and learnt a few things reading the link you provided. Just wanted to add that the foreign key UserId needed to be a string not an int.

Comment: Even with this structure, the error happens when loading children of a child (second level)

Answer (score 5):

Your `LectureCompletion` class needs a primary key to be defined properly.`[Key]` is the primary key annotation to explicitly tell EntityFramework to set this as your primary key, else convention will take over.

That is, properties that is either named `ID` or suffixed with `ID` e.g. `PokemonID` for `Pokemon` table. `ID` or `Id` is not case sensitive in this case.

The foreign key attribute is only used only if you want your foreign key property name in `LectureCompletion` class named differently than your referred class. For example, if your `ApplicationUser` class' primary key is `ApplicationUserId`, but in `LectureCompletion` class you want it to be `UserId` then you can add the attribute.

Do it like this

```
public class LectureCompletion
{
    [Key] // Defined only once
    public LectureCompletionId { get;set; }

    // Not needed if Lecture class has the primary key property of LectureId,
    // which is your case.
    [ForeignKey("Lecture")] // Name of your navigation property below.
    public int LectureId { get;set; }

    public Lecture Lecture { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public int UserId {get;set;}

    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public bool Completed { get; set; }
}
```

As for EntityFramework Core, the ColumnOrder doesn't appear to have any effect as of now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because I was missing the setter for the id property, so it was throwing this exact same error.

My key property looked like this:

```
[Key]
public Id { get; }
```

Added the setter and worked as expected:

```
[Key]
public Id { get; set; }
```